# What is the AmE and BrE for "americanata"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

***[Americanata](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/A/americanata.php)*** is a common Italian noun which is used to refer to:

> - scherz., iron. Azione, impresa fatta con grandiosità esagerata e ostentata.
>     Bizzarria di dubbio gusto: *Quello spettacolo è pieno di americanate.* (Hoepli)

Translation:

> - (jocular, ironic. Actions, feats performed with exaggerated and ostentatious grandeur. Oddities of doubtful taste. *That show is full of "americanate"*.)

The term is generally  used with a derogatory connotation to refer to a single action like "[Fonzi jumps the shark](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=t4ZGKI8vpcg)" or a movie like "[Armageddon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon_(1998_film))" for instance, which are often very popular especially among young people.

The expression is generally translated with a phrase like "exaggerated, unbelievable thing", but what is the noun in AmE and BrE that conveys the meaning suggested above?

Comment: Oh, I like this word! I'm going to use it. I'm 90% it was coined after seeing me in a bar, anyway.

Comment: Yankeeism? I am not sure whether there will be any word that has such a derogatory connotation in English.

Comment: How I would translate *Americanata*: brash, bold, showy, vulgar, over the top,.... the US is often perceived as embodying morals, ideals and beliefs which tend to go from one extreme to another. Nice question by the way.

Comment: How about "gaudy"?

Comment: Where's your list of words for us to choose from? Should that be the SWR tag and have an example sentence instead?

Comment: @Mazura - I don't have a list of words to choose from . I don't even know if there is a single word for that.

Comment: That's precisely what SWRs are for. `translation` is also n/a: you have provided one.

Comment: You've also left out *why* this word is used the way it is (and why it's derogatory): "absurdly grandiose and extravagant **behaviour, considered typical of Americans**" –[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/americanata)

Comment: I find "absurdly grandiose and extravagant behavior" to best be used to describe Britons, but that's *neither here nor there*, because I flippantly think all Britons behave like C3P0. If you're looking for a single word for [cultural racism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_racism), I'm at a loss.

Comment: As a data point, in Canada the word _American_ itself is both a neutral demonym and a more negative, political adjective. You can distinguish them by context in writing (sometimes between quotes), or by the speaker making a face of disgust or revulsion and adopting a snob, aloof tone when spitting out the word. The reason is that we Canadians often like to contrast ourselves and our policies with those down south, and people veering too close to USA positions considered unreasonable here are derided as [_American_](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-34321263).

Comment: Use air quotes when saying 'American' and try to spit a little: agreed, it already is in use as a derogatory word, worldwide, including in the US, as more and more of us become less 'centric'. @IwillnotexistIdonotexist

Comment: @Mazura - I didn't leave anything out of my translation, but you are right, it is a cultural thing. The tendency to give exaggerated representation of reality has probably been amplified in movies for entertainment reasons, but I don't think the is anything idiotic about it as you suggested in your answer. The use of these "hyperboles" is not god or bad in itself and I am not asking about opinions, but just what is the term, if there is one, to define them.

Comment: I think to get a good idea of what *americanata* is on television you have the perfect example in the three-star Michellin chef, Gordon Ramsay and his infamous food shows : *Gordon Ramasays' Kitchen Nightmares* (BrEng) and the Am Fox show *Kitchen Nightmares*. Both are entertaining but the production budget and editing in the second  is pure "americanata", and gets wearisome after a while. Whereas, the Channel 4  food show has a more self-deprecating humour, the budget is limited, and there is much less in-your-face melodrama. Anyone who has seen both shows will know what I mean.

Comment: There is a term 'Americana' which is of similar form, but has slightly different connotations, namely evokes everyday items that are essentially American feeling. It has an old-fashioned, flea-market feeling, baseball, apple-pie, maple-syrup, Christmas at granma's, salt-water taffy on vacation at the beach. Very wholesome and not disparaging at all. So don't use 'Americana' for what you want, people will get confused.

Comment: I’m thinking it’s ***Italianata***  ...   :-)

Comment: Actually there is a word *Italianate*  that has some of the connotations of floridity and doubtful taste...

Comment: Treccani includes the allusion to Americans which @Mazura said you, Josh  had taken out. Josh, can you give instances of usage that do not refer to American culture (and are not used ironically)? The word is a diminutive of *americano* after all  and your question gives two examples from American culture.

Comment: So... that Americanata get outta here before he really pisses someone off...?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't an equivalent in AmE or BrE because the term relates to a concept that is specific to Italian culture. The definition given in the question is incomplete and perhaps somewhat misleading. An americanata is essentially any behavior done by Americans that Italians don't understand, and which has an element of absurdity to it. There's generally an element of technological innovation in play as well. And while the over-the-top questionable taste stuff is perhaps the classic example, perfectly reasonable things like dental floss or seatbelts in automobiles are also americanate, or at least have been. The word relates to American things viewed from the context of Italian culture. The things in question need not actually be absurd, they just need to appear so from the point of view of the Italians.

It's also very important to understand that this word isn't really derogatory. It's lighthearted and there's usually some admiration in the mix. An americanata is largely harmless and the word is usually used as part of a funny statement. It's a put-down, but an affectionate one.

Although I can't think of any term to use, a rough equivalent of the concept is our perception of certain Japanese innovations. The culture is foreign and mysterious to us, and hyper-modern and technological. So much of it seems strange and funny, while we also recognize and admire the technical achievements that underlie it.

Comment: Exactly; I don't find anything absurd or americanata about the Fonz.

Answer (score 3):

The original sentence evokes P.T. Barnum's spectacles and exhibitions, or Buffalo Bill Cody's western show, so in America it would specifically be a [three-ring circus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/three%E2%80%93ring%20circus):

a public spectacle, especially one with little substance.

"his attempt at a dignified resignation turned into a three-ring circus"

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest may be **[kitsch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kitsch)**

> something of tawdry design, appearance, or content created to appeal to popular or undiscriminating taste.
>
> things (such as movies or works of art) that are of low quality and that many people find amusing and enjoyable

ex: The lava lamp is an example of Sixties kitsch

Comment: I think that "kitsch" covers one aspect of the term, but unluckily it misses the important aspect of "exaggerated and ostentatious grandeur" that the term conveys.

Comment: Yeah, *kitsch* isn't ostentatious, it's just tacky.

Answer (score 0):

**Vaudeville** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vaudeville)

> *mass noun*
>   1. A type of entertainment popular chiefly in the US in the early 20th century, featuring a mixture of speciality acts such as burlesque comedy and song and dance
>
> *"his comedic roots are in vaudeville"*
>   (as modifier) *"a stage show with vaudeville acts and dancing girls"*

**Burlesque** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/burlesque)

> *noun*
>   1. An absurd or comically exaggerated imitation of something, especially in a literary or dramatic work; a parody
>
> *"the funniest burlesque of opera"*
>   (as modifier) *"burlesque Shakespearean stanzas"*

**Farce** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/farce)

> *noun* A comic dramatic work using buffoonery and horseplay and typically including crude characterization and ludicrously improbable situations.
>
> *"On stage he has played character roles in farces, pantomime, comedies and serious drama."*
>   <sub>*synonyms: slapstick comedy, slapstick, burlesque, vaudeville, buffoonery*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*I'm not so sure about this, but here it is.*</sub>

**Adynaton** — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adynaton)

> 1. (rhetoric) A form of hyperbole that uses exaggeration so magnified as to express impossibility
> 2. (rhetoric) The expression of impossibility of expression.

Answer (score 0):

If [*americanate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/americanata) means, "considered typical of Americans," then the American equivalent would be [***eurocentric***](https://www.google.com/search?q=eurocentric&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8): (or the even more derogatory term listed below: *eurotrash*)

> focusing on European culture or history to the exclusion of a wider view of the world; implicitly regarding European culture as preeminent[*]. –Google

---

> *[European exceptionalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocentrism) is widely reflected in popular genres of literature, especially literature for young adults (for example, Rudyard Kipling's *Kim*) and adventure literature in general. **Portrayal of European colonialism in such literature has been analysed in terms of "Eurocentrism" in retrospect, such as presenting idealised and often exaggeratedly masculine Western heroes, who conquered 'savage' peoples in the remaining 'dark spaces' of the globe.** –Wiki

Everyone does it, the only thing that's different is the *euro* or *ameri* prefix. I.e., *Americentrism*. E.g.,:

"That show is full of "**eurotrash**."

> Self-aggrandizing Europeans who condescend Americans, yet consume massive amounts of American culture and appropriate it as their own. –[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Eurotrash)

---

"Oddities of doubtful taste," is dubious at best: beauty is in the eye of the beholder. IMO a word for an "exaggerated, unbelievable thing" (**farfetched?**) doesn't need all this context, unless this is the kind of answer you wanted.

My point is, **why would anyone invent a specific noun to call *themselves* an idiot?** However as Rathony noted, the British have *Yankeeism* for us wankers.

Comment: I think eurocentric has a very different connotation. The core connotation of an "americanata" is the exaggeration of an action to make it appear awesome, incredible but imaginatively possible. You would still need a term to describe a scene like "Fonzi jumps the shark". What is it?

Comment: @Josh61 - *over embellished*, which is not intrinsically derogatory, nor 'centric' by any means. But what good is the translation if those aren't requirements?

Comment: @Josh61 - Allow me to reiterate: you will not find an *Americanism* for this 'Euroism' (heh, now I need a word); we're not *that* stupid. Required reading: [A pedant’s guide to annoying Americanisms](http://home.bt.com/news/uk-news/a-pedants-guide-to-annoying-americanisms-11363916866278)

Comment: In contemporary Europe, the term "Eurocentric" usually describes what the EU's bureaucrats refer to as "the project" - i.e. the creation of a Federal Europe including full political and monetary union of all the member states. It's a political term, not a cultural one - even though that political concept may be described as "ostentatious grandeur" (or worse!) by non-believers.

Comment: @Josh61 - Perhaps I'm just caught up on, *this is our word for them, what's their word for us?* Asked another way: *What's the American word for "considered typical of Americans"?* - IDK, what is it called in Europe, when something is 'considered typical of Europeans'? Hashtag: 'eyeofthebeholder'.

Comment: The Italian *americanata* does *not* mean an idiotic action or person from the US. It's pretty clear from your response you've taken umbrage with the OP, when in actual fact the overall tone of the question is neutral. E.g. there must be  Americans who cringe at the huge (almost immoral) budgets spent on Hollywood movies, or when they watch the Jerry Springer Show. Isn't there a term for people who admire and support Bill O'Reilly, and Fox News? What about "your" [*rednecks*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redneck), isn't that a derogatory term toward your own compatriots?

Comment: Mazura, come to think of it Americans have invented such a word for themselves; It's related to my _American_ proposal in the comments and it would make an excellent answer for @Josh61: [_'Murica!_](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/murica) Generally used with self-deprecation by Americans and head-shaking and mockery by others. It connotes exactly what _americanata_ does and denounces: Exaggerated patriotism, grandeur, a bit of redneck, Hollywood-scale destruction and self-patting on the back.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You're slightly too quick to ascribe ulterior motive to Mazura and his answer: I'm not from the US and yet I interpreted it as translating the _cultural_ angle of _americanata_ from Italian-targeting-the-US to US-targeting-the-EU. This is a valuable answer to convey the "attitude" or "mood" that would be achieved in European readers, except OP wishes to induce these feelings in AmE readers (presumably Americans).

Answer (score 0):

In an informal context, perhaps some variation of the slang term " 'Murica " would suit your needs. This is a joking-but-derogatory abbreviation of America, often used when referring to exaggerated American stereotypes. Maybe something like " 'Murican " would convey the idea you want.